# URLs with handlebars JS

Tags: html, node.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I'm trying to use handlebars to render a url inside an email html template sent to a user after registration to do the confirmation step.

The link is assembled as follows:

```
var data = {
            user: {
                    email: body.email,
                    token: 'tmpToken',

                    link: '/confirm?email=' + body.email + '&token=' + 'tmpToken'
            },
            appName: 'XYZ'
    };
```

The link used is in the following format:

```
"/confirm?email=x&token=y"
```

Each time I the email is sent, the link is tampered with and becomes:

`"confirm/?email=y&token=y"`, which is pretty annoying.

I'm using handlebars in nodejs to refer to the url inside the html using the handlebars

`<a href="{{{link_to}}}" style="border: 0;" target="_blank">`.

I tried to do it using Handlebars helpers:

```
handlebars.registerHelper('link_to', function() {
                    return new handlebars.SafeString(handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(data.user.link));
            });
```

Any thoughts about why question marks in the string is converted to "/?" ?

Answer (score 0):

This code, based closely on the code you present, does not inject the `/`. So there's probably something else going on somewhere. But this works as expected:

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

var source = '<a href="{{{link_to}}}" style="border: 0;" target="_blank">';
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = {
            user: {
                    email: 'foo@example.com',
                    token: 'tmpToken',

                    link: '/confirm?email=' + 'foo@example.com' + '&token=' + 'tmpToken'
            },
            appName: 'XYZ'
    };

Handlebars.registerHelper('link_to', function() {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(data.user.link));
});
var result = template(data);

console.log(result);  // logs: <a href="/confirm?email=foo@example.com&amp;token=tmpToken" style="border: 0;" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Yes it's the same here, but the problem is with sending it via email, I'm using nodemailer with sendGrid, on the other side (email), the url is tampered with. I've just tried another example with the request host appended before 'localhost:3000/confirm?....' and an invalid link is rendered in the email.